# Creating a scrolling grid of different width cells on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-2d

I am new to iOS/Mac and ObjectiveC development and need a bit of guidance if someone could be so kind, so please excuse my ignorance.

The issue I have is I need to create a Grid view for a TV Guide where you have a vertical list of channel logos on the left that scrolls up and down, and to its right we have a horizontally and vertically scrolling grid. Horizontal scrolling doesnt move the channel logos which is fixed on screen, but vertically scrolling grid also scrolls the logos as you would expect.

Now being new to ObjC and iOS Frameworks, I was wondering which methods I should go down to implement this, Quartz2D perhaps? Or are their alternative simpler methods?

Whatever method is used, it needs to be quick with thousands of 'cells' across up to 600 rows; it also has to be memory efficient with out of view cells being disposed/reused as needed.

I am not necessarily asking for specific code (although that would be nice lol), just some advice on what methods to use so i can concentrate my education on those areas; if that is possible

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not really need two different scroll views / table views left and right, as the two sides should always scroll with each other.

Thus, just use a `UITableView` with a custom cell (subclass `UITableViewCell`) that has the logo on the left, and another scroll view (for horizontal scrolling) on the right.

Read Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451), and you will be on your way.

Comment: Apologies, am a bit confused by the answer. The logos must only scroll vertically and not horizontally, as you still want to see what channel the programmes are for when horizontally scrolled (see any tv guide for eg); and wouldn't stacking cells horizontally in table be really inefficient and slow?

Comment: Yes, the logos must only scroll vertically, it is the content that you want to scroll horizontal. And no, not inefficient and slow.